# Reducing ambiguity in a description that might apply to one or two nouns in a list

Tags: conjunctions, syntax, ambiguity, indirect-objects

> The state and local governments must take into account ***characteristics of family members and family types*** in coming up with the policies.

In the way it is expressed right now, there is no way to tell (it is ambiguous) if 'characteristics' is associated with both 'family members' and 'family types', or just 'family members'. How would you rephrase this so that this distinction is clear? (i.e. 'characteristics' should only be associated with 'family members')

Also, what would be the natural assumption, if there is any, as to the question of associativity of 'characteristics' in the given sentence?

Comment: Thanks for the replies, how about this: "The state and local governments must take into account characteristics of family members, as well as family types, in coming up with the policies." Does this make it more clear also, the use of 'as well as'? Or is it still the case that 'characteristics' also may be associated with 'as well as'? I think that it acts to separate "characteristics of family members" and "family types" and associate each to "take into account" - am I right on this?

Comment: It separates them, but maybe a little too much. That construction is often used for when you want to draw a contrast between the two things. It sounds to me like you meant the governments were already going to consider family types, but you are advising that they should consider characteristics of family members as well.

Comment: It doesn't always mean that you want to draw that contrast, but it usually does. It might be confusing to some people that you don't mean to.

Comment: @modulusshift I see.

Comment: @Max "... must take into account characteristics of family members, as well as family types, in coming up..." still doesn't disambiguate: it could be that you mean "characteristics of family members, as well as characteristics of family types". I would phrase as "... must take into account family types and the characteristics of family members..."

Comment: This has been closed as off-topic on the grounds that it's a proof-reading question with no specific source of concern about the text identified. I strongly disagree: the question is very explicit about what the concern with the text is and there's a follow-up question about similar situations. Voting to re-open.

Comment: @David Richerby actually, to provide more information, I would have thought that since there is this option: "must take into account characteristics of family members, as well as those of family types " (note the use of 'those'), that without 'those', it would apply to "family members" only and not "characteristics of family members"; so that there was (virtually) no ambiguity in the way 'as well as' was used in my example before

Comment: @Max No, without "those", it could either mean "characteristics of members and characteristics of types" or "types and characteristics of members". You can't use the argument "Oh, this ambiguous sentence must mean X because, if the writer had meant Y, they would have inserted some word" because that assumes the writer was aware of the ambiguity and made the irrational choice to leave the sentence ambiguous rather than just fix it.

Comment: @David Richerby:  your suggestion to reverse the order of the noun phrases is a good solution. Make it an answer and I'll upvote it, as it has more general applicability than the accepted answer, which is okay but works only when one can find a noun that encompasses both ideas.

Comment: @TRomano Done! (Actually, I was already writing up the answer as you were commenting.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't think it was ambiguous, I assumed it was just referring to the family members. But if you want to make sure no one can misunderstand you, you can just change the order. "must take into account family types and characteristics of family members" is clear.

It's kinda wordy, though. I would phrase this as:

> The state and local governments must take into account family composition in coming up with these policies.

(I used "these" because I assume you were just talking about the policies, so it directly refers back to the last couple sentences.)

"composition" means both the specific parts and the characteristics of those parts, as well as their arrangement and kinds and number, and so how they fit together. I think that covers the same meanings.

Answer (score 2):

To rephrase unambiguously, change the order of the items in the list, giving

> The state and local governments must take into account family types and characteristics of family members in coming up with the policies.

Of course, this only works because the list has only two items and "characteristics of" applies only to one of them.  For more complex constructions, such as family types, characteristics of family members and characteristics of family pets, a more significant rephrasing would be needed; perhaps something like

> ... must take into account family types and characteristics of both family members and pets...

The following suggestion by the asker in a comment doesn't work:

> The state and local governments must take into account characteristics of family members, as well as family types, in coming up with the policies.

This is still ambiguous because it could reasonably mean "... characteristics of family members, as well as characteristics of family types..."

An alternative solution is just to ignore the "problem". Anything you might consider about a thing has to be a characteristic of that thing, so "considering family types" and "considering characteristics of family types" amounts to the same thing. This is in contrast to, for example, "I don't want to go to India because of my fear of tigers and the cost of plane tickets", which you might want to rephrase to avoid the suggestion that you're afraid of the cost of plane tickets.

Answer (score 1):

*Family composition* (per modulusshift) is one way to solve this, but if you want to make sure that *characteristics of* does not apply to *family types* but applies only to *family members*, you can simply reverse the order:

> The state and local governments must take into account family types
>   and characteristics of family members in coming up with the policies.

Answer (score 0):

> The state and local governments must take into account **the**
>   characteristics of **both** family members and **family** types in
>   coming up with **their** new policies.

I read *"characteristics of family members and family types"* as one massive noun phrase.

This looks like a news article. Journalists write within the constraints of a **word count** and are renown for omitting articles and modifiers that, to them, add nothing to the telling of their story.

Comment: He was saying that "characteristics" should only refer to "family members", not both members and types.